# Jquery take value of brother element in another div

Tags: jquery

i have a this html code, with two inputs

```
<div class="boxinput">
    <div class="scarico boxvalue">
        <input id="inputscarico" class="inputscaricomerci" name="scarico--10--2015-04-25" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="reso boxvalue">
        <inputid="inputreso" class="inputscaricomerci" name="reso--10--2015-04-25" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this jquery code

```
$(".inputscaricomerci").change(function() {
    // click
    var nomecella = $(this).attr("name");
    var valorecella = $(this).val();

    // brother
}) // end event change
```

After `// brothers`, I need take the value of another input, 
I do not know what is clicked first, `.scarico` input or `.reso` input, but I need take the value of both

How I can do this ?

Comment: use the id's to get the value

Comment: Please explain problem in more detail. What is relevance of `which is clicked first`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
var scarico = $('#inputscarico').val();
var reso = $('#inputreso').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
if($(this).patent().hasClass('reso')){
  var a = $('scarico inputscaricomerci').val();
}else{
    var a = $('.reso .inputscaricomerci').val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should notice that `.change()` event on text inputs are fired when you leave that input element:

```js
var arr = [];
$('.boxinput input').change(function(){
    var o = {};
    o.nomecella = $(this).attr('name');
    o.valorecella = this.value;
    arr.push(o);
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxinput">
    <div class="scarico boxvalue">
        <input id="inputscarico" class="inputscaricomerci" name="scarico--10--2015-04-25" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="reso boxvalue">
        <input id="inputreso" class="inputscaricomerci" name="reso--10--2015-04-25" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
$(function() {
    $(".inputscaricomerci").on("focus",function() {
        var $parentDiv = $(this).closest(".boxinput");
        var order = $parentDiv.data("order"); // array or nothing
        if (order) { // exists
            order = JSON.parse(order)
            if (order.length < 2) order.push(this.id); // add this box ID
        }
        else {
            order = [this.id];
        }
        $parentDiv.data("order",JSON.stringify(order));
        console.log($parentDiv.data("order")); // shows the order
    });
});
```